# Manipulating Stylo in R

Tags: r, graph

I am trying to manipulate the graphical features of my stylo graphs. However certain lines like "plot.font.size", "plot.custom.height" etc or changing colors "col1 = "blue"" (which can also be found in the latest stylo sourcecode (stylo_0.4.0.2.r) are not working

```
library(stylo)

stylo(gui = F, mfw.min = 200, mfw.max = 500, corpus.dir = "E:/Digital Humanities/Studium/2014 Wintersemester/R/Resources/kern",
                    encoding = "UTF-8",
                    consensus.strength=0.4,
                    ###plot.font.size = 12,
                    ###plot.custom.height = 12,
                    ###plot.custom.width = 5,
                    ###plot.line.thickness = 5,
                    titles.on.graphs = TRUE,
                    ###name.of.the.method = "methodname",



                    ###dendrogram.layout.horizontal = FALSE,
                    analysis.type="CA")
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What about calling `par` first and changing parameters that way?

Comment: I am not quite sure how this would work, sorry, I am quite new to R :/